# incrementing a counter in asp mvc view page for inserting a field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to append a field based on the click event. I want to also increment the counter while doing this.

I currently have this:

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
var i = 0;
}
```

Beginform code omitted

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Images[0].ImageUrl, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div id="addhiddenimagefield">
        </div>
        <div id="counterincrement">
        </div>
        @*@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Images[0].ImageUrl, new { id = "updateimageurl" })*@
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" id="tbx-file-path" class="form-control" value="No file chosen..." readonly="readonly" />

            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                <span>Select file...</span>
                @*@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Images[0].ImageUrl, new { id = "fu-my-simple-upload", type = "file", name = "myfile" })*@

                <input class="text-box single-line" type="file" name="myfile" id="fu-my-simple-upload" />
            </span>

            <div><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" id="hl-start-upload">Start Upload</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my script code. Some of it is omitted to maintain the size of this question.

```
$("#hl-start-upload").on('click', function () {

      $("#addhiddenimagefield").prepend('@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Images[i].ImageUrl, new { id = "updateimageurl" })');
});
```

I want to increment the index counter "i" so that I can add more fields as the button is clicked. I've tried many ways but none have worked so far. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the purpose of the line `$("#...").prepend('@Html.HiddenFor(model =>`?, you are prepending the server side code to DOM, which is of no use. No were it will be processed. What are you trying to achieve at first place?

Comment: It appears to be working for me. With the click of a button I'm uploading an image file. I want to store the image url into my database model. There can be any number of images to upload. There is other form data that I have to store along with the image url. So I have one model for other information and one model for images of those there could be many which are related using the foreign key and one to many relationship.

Comment: if the server side code is throwing you off, this also works:
$("#addhiddenimagefield").prepend('<input type="hidden" name="Images[0].ImageUrl" id="#updateimageurl">');

except instead of the 0 I would like to put an index variable i which I will have to increment on each click event on the client side

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the Html.HiddenFor helper method, I wrote out the html in this way and use the client side to increment the variable like this:

```
            $("#addhiddenimagefield").prepend('<input type="hidden" name="Images[#s].ImageUrl" id="updateimageurl" value="">'.replace('#s',String(i++)));
```